# Magento 2 . How to place review form in the Items Ordered (sales/order/view/order_id)

Tags: review

Can any one suggest. how to place review form in the Items Ordered (sales/order/view/order_id) Magento 2

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

**You need to extend the sales_order_view.xml file in your design/module and add a block with a review form like the one on the product details page (see catalog_product_view.xml layout).**

For example, to customize the layout defined in `<Magento_Sales_module_dir>/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_view.xml`, you need to add a layout file with the same name in your custom theme, such as: `<theme_dir>/Magento_Sales/layout/sales_order_view.xml`. Then do your customizations on the layout xml.

**Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.view">
            <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review"
                   name="reviews.tab" as="reviews"
                   template="Magento_Review::review.phtml"
                   ifconfig="catalog/review/active">
                <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form"
                       name="product.review.form" as="review_form"
                       ifconfig="catalog/review/active">
                    <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before"
                               label="Review Form Fields Before"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```